# views page display is not rendering anything

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views

I've created a view type page, and I specified the field and the filter criteria, and the result is showing on the preview. But the page is not displaying anything. What did I do wrong?

Comment: There could be several thousand things wrong for all we know... You could show us the code to help us help you?

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear your drupal site cache
Go to admin/config/development/performance and clear cache or
admin/structure/views/settings/advanced and clear views cache